# Geth private network security

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, security

I'm implementing a private network with Geth, which is expected to go into production for a client.
What are the most important points to focus on regarding the **security** of my blockchain?

I was thinking of implementing a proxy server to reach my JSON-RPC endpoint and managing accounts through Metamask.

Are there other things I should be cautious about?